# Size of table with few columns

Tags: python, datatable, impala

I have a table with 600+ columns and 5 years of data which is about 10TB in size. Is it possible to get the size of this table, if recreated with 15 selected columns for just the last 2 years?
I am trying to create a temporary table with the needed columns and history, but the create table query fails each time or times out with error 'Results have expired, rerun the query if needed.'
Can anyone suggest a better way to get the size? Thanks in advance.

Comment: "_get the size_" - Do you mean _estimate_ the size (without actually creating the new table)? If so, I don't think there is enough information in the question to answer that in any reliable way.

Comment: `Results have expired` - This means your SQL is taking very long time. Try this from some CMD prompt or reduce the date to see if it runs faster. Also, you can think about using some partition in the table.